# How to remove CD/DVD image from Virtual Media Manager in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, disk-image

I had a DVD image attached to Virtualbox via Virtual Media Manager and had it deleted from my harddrive without removing or "releasing" it from Virtual Media Manager.

Now the image is still shown in Virtual Media Manager but the remove and release options are greyed out.

Is there a way to get rid of the image shown in Virtual Media Manager?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That entry is not a problem. If you want to remove it, then place the CD/DVD-image in the exact same location it was originally loaded from, load the virtual HDD, unmount it from the Virtualization, then turn off the virtual HDD and remove from the list, and then delete the DVD-image file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the VBoxGuestAdditions, I don't believe that this can be removed.  It's integral to VirtualBox, available from the Devices menu of any virtual machine.  If it's a general DVD iso or similar, you should be able to delete it by ejecting it from any virtual machines using it, then choosing the remove option in the Virtual Media Manager.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work with the GUI you can try editing the XML files VirtualBox uses to store its parameters.

Under

```
gedit ~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
```

You'll find  tags with separate tags for Disks, DVDs and Floppies.